# Center a block of images with CSS

Tags: html, css

Using the box model I’ve created a 3 by 3 grid of images. I wanted all the images centered so I wrapped all the images in a div and set the padding-left to 10%.
This worked but I’m assuming it wasn’t the correct way of doing this, so I’m asking for someone to tell me what I should’ve done instead.
HTML and CSS below…

```css
img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.1%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.block {
  padding-left:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
  <img src="placeholder.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a CSS grid for this type of thing. Your CSS would look something like this for a 3x3 grid:

```
.block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/b0orL9hm/9/)

If you want to learn more about css grids there's also plenty of tutorials out there. If you don't know where to start, [this one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)'s pretty helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the following CSS:

```
.block {
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 700px;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin: 0.1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I’m wrong but this would centre the block would it not?  Just add your padding to that...?

```
.block {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Nah this doesn't work..
Well I did what you said and added the padding but nothing changed, it remained in the center due to the padding, I think?

Answer (score 0):

```
.block {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Wiki Babu, Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer is correct, it's good practice here to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. The goal is to help others learn *why* an answer works. For more information read [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

update your css like this

```
block{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
block img{
    width:33.33%;
}
```

Comment: This does not what the OP wanted but rather puts all images in one line: https://jsfiddle.net/b0orL9hm/15/

Comment: just need to add property `flex-wrap:wrap;`